# Multilingual Websites in ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: asp.net, multilingual

I want to develop a multilingual website which will have the Swedish, Dutch & Arabic language support. I Google a lot and found following are the ways to develop this:

1. Using Resource Files (Traditional way):  It doesn't seems to be an elegant solution as I have to maintain separate resource file for each language and for each page of my website.
2. Using Google Translator: I explored following code and found that it works fine, however not in every case,

public string TranslateText(string input, string languagePair)
    {
        string url = String.Format("http://www.google.com/translate_t?hl=en&ie=UTF8&text={0}&langpair={1}", input, languagePair);
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        WebProxy proxyObj = new WebProxy("http://ipAddress:port");

```
    proxyObj.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    webClient.Proxy = proxyObj;
    webClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
      string result = webClient.DownloadString(url);
    int index = result.IndexOf("id=result_box");
    int startIndex = index + 33;

    result = result.Substring(startIndex, result.Length - startIndex);
    result = result.Substring(0, result.IndexOf("</div"));
    return result;
}
```

1. Using Google Translator Bar: I have seen Google Translator bar on some sites, like Wikipedia, which allows users to change the entire content of the site to his/her desired language.

I want to know is there any other way for doing this and which is the best professional way for doing this.

Comment: Honestly go for resources, Google translate is great for getting what something is about but it often gets the grammar wrong and makes it look like your site was written by a 4 year old. Resources may be a pain but they how most professional developers do it.

Comment: Thanks Saint, But I think there is one more problem with the Resources approach i.e. How can I convert the dynamic data coming from some database or from some where else.

Comment: You seem to be at odds with what you want. You want something automatic and profesional un-fortunatly translation systems just arn't there yet. Go with Google translate if you want somthing automatic, hire a translator and use resourcesif you want something professional.